# The gateway did not receive a response from 'Microsoft.Web' within the specified time period while creating FTP in Azure

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-logic-apps, connector

I have an Azure logic app, inside that i am creating FTP (when file is added or modified) but after creation of FTP connection, i am unable to see the folder name inside the folder box with the error "The gateway did not receive a response from 'Microsoft.Web' within the specified time period".
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the steps in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-ftp#prerequisites) create the FTP connector?

I think the problem is you didn't open the passive mode, the mode is a prerequisite asked in the doc. Due to environmental constraints, I couldn't open the passive mode, you could try it. And you need make sure you server is accessible from the internet.

If you still have questions, please let me know.